# A bag has n cards labeled from 1 to n and a person has the option to play 2 two games, either Game A or Game B.

Tags: probability

A bag has n cards labeled from 1 to n and a person has the option to play 2
two games, either Game A or Game B.

In Game A, a person picks a random number from 1 to n, and then pulls a card
from the bag. If the card matches the number they chose, they ‘lose’ the game.
However, if the card doesn’t match the chosen number, they keep the card and
pick another one.

To win the game, the person must continue picking un-matching numbers until
their chosen number is the only remaining card in the bag.
In Game B, a person must choose a random number between 1 and n. To win
the game, a person must draw out their chosen number on the first attempt.
Show that both games have equal probability of winning.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The chosen number is just as likely to be first (or $17$-th) as it is to be last.